# How to get element value in complex JSON data

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

In the below JSON data are service objects, which contains multiple set of objects. Each object contains itemCode object and bCode value. I need to look for each bCode from each itemCode object and compare with a list if bcode value matches with any list item print description.
I am not able to create path to each bcode.

```
{
    "getResponse": {
        "dID": "B03",
        "aNumber": "45901",
        "services": [
            {
                "sIdentifier": "1",
                "itemCode": {
                    "bCode": "LAX005",
                    "eCode": "BASICSPPA",
                    "description": "Residential 50 ",
                    "lDescription": "SPPA Basic 01"
                },       
            },
            {
                "serviceIdentifier": "1",
                "itemCode": {
                    "bcode": "LAY010",
                    "ecode": "EXPBASICSPPA",
                    "description": "100",
                    "lDescription": "Residential 100"
                },
            },
            {
                "serviceIdentifier": "1",
                "itemCode": {
                    "bcode": "LAZ045",
                    "ecode": "FEEVBSURSP",
                    "description": " 200",
                    "lDescription": "Residential 200"
                },
            },
            {
                "serviceIdentifier": "1",
                "itemCode": {
                    "bcode": "LABX700",
                    "ecode": "HSIBASESPPA",
                    "description": "300",
                    "lDescription": "Residential 300"
                },
            },
            {
                "serviceIdentifier": "1",
                "itemCode": {
                    "bcode": "LABX905",
                    "ecode": "SPVTELLN00",
                    "description": "400",
                    "lDescription": "Residential 400"
                },
            },
        ],
        "sourceSystem": "04:00"
    }
}
```

I am trying something like this

```
public static void CreateObject()
    {
        List<string> bCode = new List<string>();
        string[] codes = { "BA00010", "BA00012", "BA00050", "BA00020", "BA00022", "BA00025", "BA00030", "LAZ045", "BA00040", "BA00060", "LA700" };
        billerCode.AddRange(codes);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = DATA.Length;
        using (Stream webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(DATA);
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (webStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                    {
                        var response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                        var json = JObject.Parse(response);

                        dynamic deSerData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json.ToString());
                        Dictionary<string, object> qoset_object= deSerData["getResponse"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                        foreach (var item in qoset_object)
                        {
                            if (item.Key == "services")
                            {
                                List<string> ut = new List<string>();
                              //  ut.Add(item.Value);

                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var item in bCode)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("-----------------");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested only in some of properties, instead of deserializing JSON to new class you can work with JObject:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = new List<string>();
var myBCodes = new List<string> {"LAX005"};

foreach (var jToken in obj["getResponse"]["services"].Select(s => s["itemCode"]))
{
    if (myBCodes.Contains(jToken["bCode"].ToString()))
        result.Add(jToken["description"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: This approach works fine, I didnt think of jTokens , thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create this kind of modal

```
public class GetResponse
{
   public strin dID{ get; set; }
   public string aNumber{ get; set; }
   public services services{ get; set; }
   public string sourceSystem { get; set; }
}

public class services 
{
   public string sIdentifier{ get; set; }
   public List<itemCode> itemCode{ get; set; }      
}

public class itemCode
{
   public string bcode{ get; set; }
   public string ecode{ get; set; }
   public string description{ get; set; }
   public string lDescription{ get; set; }      
}

  GetResponse  getResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetResponse>(json.ToString());

//After that you will use foreach loop and get value from modal
```

Comment: The actual JSON is more complex and will not work with model approach as I dont need to look for all the data.

Comment: The complexity of the model might be irrevelent since Visual studio let you "Paste as JSON class" a json string. This will create all the class for you.